# Condición en Evento Ajax, primefaces

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

tengo una tabla de datos que al hacer doble clic sobre un mensaje muestra una pantalla con la información.

El problema es que según el tipo de mensaje tiene que abrir una pantalla diferente.

Ejemplo: 
Tengo 2 equipos y una tabla de jugadores.

Madrid y Barça
Modric, Messi, ... Pues quiero que si pulsa en Messi salga una pantalla y si pulsa en Modric salga otra.

Quiero que al pulsar en un jugador del Madrid salga este evento por ejemplo y al pulsar en un jugador del Barça salga otro.

```
<p:ajax event="rowDblselect" listener="# {transitoBean.loadData(canalBean.selectedRX.transitId)}"
                                    global="false"                      
                                    oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed){ PF('transit').show();}"
                                    update=":transitID form:growl"/>
```

Llevo 1 día dandole vueltas y sigo igual.
Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

en el metodo `loadData` hacer lo siguiente:

```
public void loadData(string transitId)){

  if(transitId.equals("messi")){
     RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('transitMessi').show();")
  }
  else if(transitId.equals("lucas")){
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('transitLucas').show();")
  }
}
```

Y en el ajax asi:

```
<p:ajax event="rowDblselect" listener="# {transitoBean.loadData(canalBean.selectedRX.transitId)}"
                                    global="false"                      
                                    update=":transitID form:growl"/>
```